# match changes by words, not by characters

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, diff, difflib

I'm using `difflib`'s `SequenceMatcher` to `get_opcodes()` and than highlight the changes with `css` to create some kind of web `diff`.

First, I set a `min_delta` so that I consider two strings different if only 3 or more characters in the whole string differ, one after another (`delta` means a real, encountered delta, which sums up all one-character changes):

```py
matcher = SequenceMatcher(source_str, diff_str)
min_delta = 3
delta = 0

for tag, i1, i2, j1, j2 in matcher.get_opcodes():
    if tag == "equal":
        continue  # nothing to capture here
    elif tag == "delete":
        if source_str[i1:i2].isspace():
            continue  # be whitespace-agnostic
        else:
            delta += (i2 - i1)  # delete i2-i1 chars
    elif tag == "replace":
        if source_str[i1:i2].isspace() or diff_str[j1:j2].isspace():
            continue  # be whitespace-agnostic
        else:
            delta += (i2 - i1)  # replace i2-i1 chars
    elif tag == "insert":
        if diff_str[j1:j2].isspace():
            continue  # be whitespace-agnostic
        else:
            delta += (j2 - j1)  # insert j2-j1 chars

return_value = True if (delta > min_delta) else False
```

This helps me to determine, if two strings really differ. Not very efficient, but I didn't think anything better out.

Then, I colorize the differences between two strings in the same way:

```py
for tag, i1, i2, j1, j2 in matcher.get_opcodes():
    if tag == "equal":
        # bustling with strings, inserting them in <span>s and colorizing
    elif tag == "delete":
        # ...

return_value = old_string, new_string
```

And the result looks pretty ugly (blue for replaced, green for new and red for deleted, nothing for equal):

[image: example]

**So**, this is happening because `SequenceMatcher` matches *every single character*. But I want for it to match *every single word* instead (and probably whitespaces around them), or something even more eye-candy because as you can see on the screenshot, the first book is actually moved on the fourth position.

It seems to me that something could be done with `isjunk` and `autojunk` parameters of `SequenceMatcher`, but I can't figure out how to write `lambda`s for my purposes.

Thus, I have two **questions**:

1. Is it possible to match by words? Is it possible to do using `get_opcodes()` and `SequenceMatcher`? If not, what could by used instead?
2. Okay, this is rather a corollary, but nevertheless: if matching by words is possible, then I can get rid of the dirty hacks with `min_delta` and return `True` as soon as at least one word differs, right?

Comment: ... didn't occurr to you that `True if delta > min_delta else False` is *exactly the same* as simply `delta > min_delta`?

Comment: Good point! When I'm writing the code this is just a way to add more clearness for myself. I usually refactor the code after to remove unneeded verbosity and to inline some operations. This time I forgot to do this on an example.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`SequenceMatcher` can accept lists of `str` as input.

You can first split the input into words, and then use `SequenceMatcher` to help you diff words. Then your colored diff would be *by words* instead of *by characters*.

```
>>> def my_get_opcodes(a, b):
...     s = SequenceMatcher(None, a, b)
...     for tag, i1, i2, j1, j2 in s.get_opcodes():
...         print('{:7}   a[{}:{}] --> b[{}:{}] {!r:>8} --> {!r}'.format(
...             tag, i1, i2, j1, j2, a[i1:i2], b[j1:j2]))
... 

>>> my_get_opcodes("qabxcd", "abycdf")
delete    a[0:1] --> b[0:0]      'q' --> ''
equal     a[1:3] --> b[0:2]     'ab' --> 'ab'
replace   a[3:4] --> b[2:3]      'x' --> 'y'
equal     a[4:6] --> b[3:5]     'cd' --> 'cd'
insert    a[6:6] --> b[5:6]       '' --> 'f'

# This is the bad result you currently have.
>>> my_get_opcodes("one two three\n", "ore tree emu\n")
equal     a[0:1] --> b[0:1]      'o' --> 'o'
replace   a[1:2] --> b[1:2]      'n' --> 'r'
equal     a[2:5] --> b[2:5]    'e t' --> 'e t'
delete    a[5:10] --> b[5:5]  'wo th' --> ''
equal     a[10:13] --> b[5:8]    'ree' --> 'ree'
insert    a[13:13] --> b[8:12]       '' --> ' emu'
equal     a[13:14] --> b[12:13]     '\n' --> '\n'

>>> my_get_opcodes("one two three\n".split(), "ore tree emu\n".split())
replace   a[0:3] --> b[0:3] ['one', 'two', 'three'] --> ['ore', 'tree', 'emu']

# This may be the result you want.
>>> my_get_opcodes("one two emily three ha\n".split(), "ore tree emily emu haha\n".split())
replace   a[0:2] --> b[0:2] ['one', 'two'] --> ['ore', 'tree']
equal     a[2:3] --> b[2:3] ['emily'] --> ['emily']
replace   a[3:5] --> b[3:5] ['three', 'ha'] --> ['emu', 'haha']

# A more complicated example exhibiting all four kinds of opcodes.
>>> my_get_opcodes("one two emily three yo right end\n".split(), "ore tree emily emu haha yo yes right\n".split())
replace   a[0:2] --> b[0:2] ['one', 'two'] --> ['ore', 'tree']
equal     a[2:3] --> b[2:3] ['emily'] --> ['emily']
replace   a[3:4] --> b[3:5] ['three'] --> ['emu', 'haha']
equal     a[4:5] --> b[5:6]   ['yo'] --> ['yo']
insert    a[5:5] --> b[6:7]       [] --> ['yes']
equal     a[5:6] --> b[7:8] ['right'] --> ['right']
delete    a[6:7] --> b[8:8]  ['end'] --> []
```

You can also diff *by line*, *by book*, or *by segments*. You only need to prepare a function that can preprocess the whole passage string into desired diff chunks.

For example:

- To diff *by line* - You probably could use `splitlines()`
- To diff *by book* - You probably could implement a function that strips off the `1.`, `2.`
- To diff *by segments* - You could throw in the API like this way `([book_1, author_1, year_1, book_2, author_2, ...], [book_1, author_1, year_1, book_2, author_2, ...])`. And then your coloring would be *by segment*.