# Python, compare two sentence by words using difflib

Tags: python, analysis, difference, cpu-word, difflib

Im using difflib and tried to compare the two sentence and get the difference.

Somewhat like this.

[image: https://text-compare.com/]

i have this code but instead of word by word it analyzed letter by letter.

```
import difflib

# define original text
# taken from: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Information_Services
original = ["IIS 8.5 has several improvements related"]

# define modified text
edited = ["It has several improvements related"]

# initiate the Differ object
d = difflib.Differ()

# calculate the difference between the two texts
diff = d.compare(original, edited)

# output the result
print ('\n'.join(diff))
```

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39001097/match-changes-by-words-not-by-characters

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you remove the `[]'s` from your strings, and call `.split()` on them in the `.compare()` perhaps you'll get what you want.

```
import difflib

# define original text
# taken from: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Information_Services
original = "IIS 8.5 has several improvements related"

# define modified text
edited = "It has several improvements related"

# initiate the Differ object
d = difflib.Differ()

# calculate the difference between the two texts
diff = d.compare(original.split(), edited.split())

# output the result
print ('\n'.join(diff))
```

Output

```
+ It
- IIS
- 8.5
  has
  several
  improvements
  related
```

Comment: Working just fine, It's quite a long time that I've searched for this. Many thanks. ;)