# Python - compare two string by words using difflib and print only difference

Tags: python, output, difference, difflib

Python newbie here. I have the following code to compare two strings using difflab library.
The output is prefixed with '+','-' for words which are different.
How to get only the differences printed without any prefix?

The expected output for the below code is

Not in first string: Nvdia

Not in first string: IBM

Not in second string: Microsoft

Not in second string: Google

Not in second string: Oracle

or just *Nvdia, IBM, Microsoft, Google, Oracle*

```
import difflib

original = "Apple Microsoft Google Oracle"
edited = "Apple Nvdia IBM"

# initiate the Differ object
d = difflib.Differ()

# calculate the difference between the two texts
diff = d.compare(original.split(), edited.split())

# output the result
print ('\n'.join(diff))
```

Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python, compare two sentence by words using difflib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63156252/python-compare-two-sentence-by-words-using-difflib)

Comment: Even better pointer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39075165/2893408

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't *have* to use `difflib`, you could use a `set` and string splitting!

```py
>>> original = "Apple Microsoft Google Oracle"
>>> edited = "Apple Nvdia IBM"
>>> set(original.split()).symmetric_difference(set(edited.split()))
{'IBM', 'Google', 'Oracle', 'Microsoft', 'Nvdia'}
```

You can also get the shared members with the `.intersection()`

```py
>>> set(original.split()).intersection(set(edited.split()))
{'Apple'}
```

The Wikipedia has a good section on basic set operations with accompanying Venn diagrams
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_(mathematics)#Basic_operations

---

However, if you have to use `difflib` (some strange environment or assignment) you can also just find every member with a `+-` prefix and slice off the all the prefixes

```py
>>> diff = d.compare(original.split(), edited.split())
>>> list(a[2:] for a in diff if a.startswith(("+", "-")))
['Nvdia', 'IBM', 'Microsoft', 'Google', 'Oracle']
```

---

All of these operations result in an iterable of strings, so you can `.join()` 'em together or similar to get a single result as you do in your Question

```py
>>> print("\n".join(result))
IBM
Google
Oracle
Microsoft
Nvdia
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I do not have to use difflib. is there any way to get the common word in the string, in this case 'Apple'.

Comment: anytime! yes, it'd be the set [intersection](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.intersection) (`&` shorthand) `set(original.split()).intersection(set(edited.split()))` `{'Apple'}`

Comment: Fantastic thanks again!. In order to get the individual words in the set, do I have to convert it to string and extract the words or is there any easy way to achieve it?

Comment: hmm.. the result is already an iterable of strings, so if if you wanted them split into lines like in your Question, you can just `.join()` 'em all together `"\n".join(resulting_set)` or any other similar mechanism

Comment: I updated my Answer with some more information about this, though often it's useful to have a `set` or `list` of values, or create a generator of them (as `difflib.Differ()` [yields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/231767/what-does-the-yield-keyword-do)) rather than converting back to a string immediately (and only doing so when you want some final output or information or are debugging)

Comment: Awesome.. thanks a lot for your time and explanation.